# How can i replace string beetwen tags <img src="example.com"/> in PHP?

Tags: php, string, tags, substring

How can I replace strings between tags like `<img src="xxxx">` inside a string?

```
$string ="<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.ewrfcds.jpg"/> this is my pictures <img src="www.google.jpg"/>";
```

I need to modify the contents of the tag `<img src="www.google.jpg"/>` to `<img src="www.myImages.jpg"/>`.

Desired output:

```
$string ="<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.myImages1.jpg"/> this is my pictures <img src="www.myImages2.jpg"/>";
```

Comment: with code. sweet sweet code

Comment: Use preg_replace, you would need to have some regular expressions knowledge http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize there is already an answer related to using the DOM.  Without doing so, you can accomplish what you're needing but with PHP.

```
$string = '<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.ewrfcds.jpg"/> this is my pictures <img src="www.google.jpg"/>';

// Get all the matches from the string
preg_match_all('/<img src="(.*?)"\/>/', $string, $matches);

// Create the regex pattern for each match
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    $patterns[] = '/' . $match . '/';
}

// Set the replacements
$replacements = array('www.myImages1.jpg', 'www.myImages2.jpg');

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

**Output:**

```
<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.myImages1.jpg"/> this is my pictures <img src="www.myImages2.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use DOM rather than regular expressions. Since the replacement involve several different image sources the solution depends on how you want to specify which image to be replaced with which. The code below will replace the image sources based on an array of URLs. First image in your string will get first source of the array, and so on.

```
<?php

$string     = '<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.ewrfcds.jpg"/> this is my pictures <img src="www.google.jpg"/>';
$imgUrls    = array('www.myImages1.jpg', 'www.myImages2.jpg');
$doc        = new DOMDocument();
$i          = 0;

$doc->loadHTML($string);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($images as $image) {

    $image->setAttribute('src', $imgUrls[$i]);
    $i++;
}

$newString  = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $newString;

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<h1> hi, My name is Bob</h1><img src="www.myImages1.jpg"> this is my pictures <img src="www.myImages2.jpg">
```

Comment: It appears that the OP is wanting to replace each image source with different URLs, considering they have 'www.myImages1.jpg' and 'www.myImages2.jpg'

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank you for notice!